# Find first date of previous week in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have some dates and week numbers and first day of week is 5 (Friday) in SQL Server. Now I want to calculate previous week and week start date from this below query.

```
DECLARE @LocationID tinyint = 1,
     @FromDate date = '2016-05-20',
     @ToDate date = '2016-05-29';

--Step1: ==================================================================
--SET first day of the week of the year
DECLARE @CurrentDayOfWeek INT
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- normalize current dkoray of week to Monday
SET @CurrentDayOfWeek = DATEPART(DW, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
SET DATEFIRST @CurrentDayOfWeek -- first day of week is now 5 (Friday)

--SELECT @CurrentDayOfWeek

-----Get Weekend number--------------
DECLARE @WeekStart int, @WeekEnd int

SET @WeekStart=(SELECT { fn WEEK( @FromDate) })
SET @WeekEnd=(SELECT { fn WEEK( @ToDate) })

;WITH AllDate AS 
(
    SELECT @FromDate as TheDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, TheDate)
    FROM AllDate 
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, TheDate) <= @ToDate
),
AllDateDetail AS 
(
    SELECT TheDate, 
        DATEPART(WEEK, TheDate) AS WeekNumber,
        YEAR(TheDate) AS [Year], 
        UPPER(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(3),DATENAME(WEEKDAY, TheDate))) AS [DayName]        
    FROM AllDate
)
SELECT 
    *
    , CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(WK, DATEDIFF(WK, 0, TheDate), 0)) AS LastWeekStart
    , { fn WEEK( CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(WK, DATEDIFF(WK, 0, TheDate) - 1, 0))) } AS WeekNumber
FROM AllDateDetail


--Select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0) as LastWeekStart
--Select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0) as ThisWeekStart
--Select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0) as NextWeekStart
```

The current result of this query:

[image]

Expected result:

```
TheDate WeekNumber  [Year]  [DayName]   LastWeekStart   LastWeekNumber
20-05-2016  21  2016    FRI 13-05-2016  20
21-05-2016  21  2016    SAT 13-05-2016  20
22-05-2016  21  2016    SUN 13-05-2016  20
23-05-2016  21  2016    MON 13-05-2016  20
24-05-2016  21  2016    TUE 13-05-2016  20
25-05-2016  21  2016    WED 13-05-2016  20
26-05-2016  21  2016    THU 13-05-2016  20
27-05-2016  22  2016    FRI 20-05-2016  21
28-05-2016  22  2016    SAT 20-05-2016  21
29-05-2016  22  2016    SUN 20-05-2016  21
```

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Instead of trying to build a recursive CTE for this, it might be a lot easier just to build a table like this, either for example using cursor or even in excel and store that in your database.

Comment: I have updated my questions, just see and do not try to use cursor.

Comment: I didn't mean using cursor in the SQL, but for populating a table. That makes everything more simple, you have to do it just once, and quite likely it out performs any recursive methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's some handy ways of calculating First/Last day of This/Last week respecting `DATEFIRST` that I blogged a couple of weeks ago.

```
SET DATEFIRST 5 --Friday
-- Start/End of Weeks respecting DATEFIRST
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,  1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()) 'First Day of Current Week (DATEFIRST)';
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,  7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()) 'Last Day of Current Week (DATEFIRST)';
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -6-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()) 'First Day of Last Week (DATEFIRST)';
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,  0-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()) 'Last Day of Last Week (DATEFIRST)';
```

(Gratuitous blog promo https://www.rednotebluenote.com/2016/04/first-day-of-the-week-and-datefirst/ )